# Error in knitting Rmarkdown file - occurred after installing tidyverse

Tags: r, r-markdown

I had created an Rmarkdown file where I read in a csv file downloaded from https://dq-content.s3.amazonaws.com/505/covid19.csv.  I have the file saved with the name covid19.csv in the same folder as my Rmd file and am repeatedly getting the following error:

```
Error in check_dots_empty(action=warn) : unused argument
(action = warn) Calls: <Anonymous> ... format.tbl-> 
trunc_mat -> shrink_mat -> <Anonymous> Execution halted
```

The file compiled without trouble before I installed the `tidyverse`, `stringr`, and `stringi` packages.  I am using Rstudio version 1.2.5033.  Could one of these packages be causing the error?

Deleting the first line where the error occurred in my file just created the same error later in the file.  I created a new file with just the following R chunk and am still getting the same error.  (It will knit if I remove `head(covid_df)` from the below code. It also will knit if I just manually create a data frame called `my_df` and then look at `head(my_df)`.):

```
library(readr)
covid_df<-read_csv("covid19.csv")
head(covid_df)
```

Comment: This is a bug in the new `tibble` version. It was discussed on the R-devel mailing list a few weeks ago and has already been reported to the developers of `tibble`

Comment: Thanks for this - is there anything I can do now to work around this, or do I just need to wait until it's fixed by the `tibble` developers?